# Как отправить на контроллер все строки из foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть у меня `View` которая отображает определенные данные. Я хочу добавить `checkbox` для каждой строки и передать это все в контроллер.

```
@model List<PlumbingCalculation>

<form method="post" asp-action="IncludeCalculationSelectData" asp-controller="Plumbing" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.Id">
        <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                @{foreach (PlumbingCalculation item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="col" />
                                <input type="hidden" value="false" name="col" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden"  name="col" asp-for="@item.CalculationName" />
                                @item.CalculationName
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Далее" />
    </form>
```

На View выводит 3 элемента.

Модель:

```
public class PlumbingCalculation
    {
        public int PlumbingCalculationId { get; set; }
        public int PlumbingMainId { get; set; }
        public string CalculationName { get; set; }
        //
        [NotMapped]
        public bool isChecked { get; set; }

        public PlumbingMain PlumbingMain { get; set; }
    }
```

Но я не понимаю, как передать коллекцию в контроллер.
Я пробовал так:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult IncludeCalculationSelectData(int id, List<PlumbingCalculation> col)
        {
                     ViewBag.count = names.Count();
                     return View("test");
        }
```

Количество : 0

Comment: Метод который получает View: 

`[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult IncludeCalculationSelectData(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.Id = id;
            return View(_context.PlumbingCalculations.Where(m => m.PlumbingMainId == id).ToList());
        }`

Answer (score 0):

У меня так и не получилось передать коллекцию объектов целиком, я
исправил параметр `name` в `input` и передал в контроллер каждый `imput` как отдельную коллекцию:

```
@{foreach (PlumbingCalculation item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="checkbox" />
                                <input type="hidden" value="false" name="checkbox" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden"  name="CalculationName" asp-for="@item.CalculationName" />
                                @item.CalculationName
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
```

Контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult IncludeCalculationSelectData(int id, List<bool> checkbox, List<string> CalculationName )
        {
                     ViewBag.count = CaclulationName.Count();
                     return View("test");
        }
```

На выходе я получил свои 3 элемента. Возможно кто-то найдет более приемлемое решение. Был бы рад услышать.

Answer (score 0):

Через создание контекста данных в Entity Framework

```
    public class BookContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<PlumbingCalculation> plumbingCalculation { get; set; }
    }
```

Создаете в контроллере экземпляр контекста и передаете через ViewBag в методе действия

Comment: Не следует использовать ViewBag, ViewData, надо пользоваться стандартным для MVC способом — ViewModel